# What does seq_lengths mean in tensorflow.reverse arguments?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to the tensorflow world. With tensorflow.reverse_sequence we need to pass sequential_length but what are its exact requirements?

I played with the values provided in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reverse_sequence). I cant grasp the concept. I'm curious about its properties and exact usage.

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

#seq_lengths = [7, 2, 3, 5] 

seq_lengths = [0, 0, 0, 0]
input = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
output = tf.reverse_sequence(input, seq_lengths, seq_axis=1, batch_axis=0)
print(output)
```

Comment: The link to the docs seem to explain it pretty well. "for each slice `i`, reverses the first `seq_lengths[i]` elements along the dimension `seq_axis`". So if `seq_list` is all ones or all zeros nothing happens. because the 0th or 1st elements reversed still gives you the same order. if you pass `[7, 2, 3, 5] ` on the other hand you should see the difference. Could you print your results?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand it now. The numbers indicates, reverse sequence till that number.

Comment: If I dont know the size and want to reverse everything then I can use `len(input[0]),.` or is there something to make this easy?

Comment: Yes unfortunately `tf.reverse_sequence` accepts not a single value for `seq_length` so you have to get the `batchsize` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the answer is already present in the comment, i'm answering here for the community.

`seq_lengths` is a 1-D with values in `int32`, `int64`, value should not exceed the length of the input array.

To explain to you how it works, here is the example.

```
seq_lengths = [2,2,2,2] 

input = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
output = tf.reverse_sequence(input, seq_lengths, seq_axis=1, batch_axis=0)
```

**Output:**

```
tf.Tensor(
[[2 1 3 4 5 0 0 0]
 [2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [2 1 3 4 0 0 0 0]
 [2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8]], shape=(4, 8), dtype=int32)
```

As you can see, I have given seq_lengths of 2 for all the input array, which means only first 2 elements of each array will be reversed, rest will remain in the original order of sequence.

You can try giving any number in seq_lengths (max 8 in the above case) and try yourself.

Comment: @Rifat - If you think i have answered your question, please UpVote and accept the answer, Thank you.